# Confusion using Yarn Resource Manager

Tags: python, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a simple pyspark job in Amazon AWS and it is configured to use Yarn via spark-default.conf file. I am slightly confused about the Yarn deployment code.

I see some example code as below:

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
conf.setAppName('spark-yarn')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

And I am not sure how I should execute the spark job in this case when 'yarn-client' is specified. I usually do it as follows:

```
$spark-submit --deploy-mode client spark-job.py
```

But what is the difference between

```
$spark-submit --deploy-mode client spark-job.py
```

and

```
$spark-submit spark-job.py
```

How do I identify looking at spark logs whether the job ran in client mode or cluster or yarn-client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `--deploy-mode` is client.
So both the below spark-submit will run in client mode.

```
$spark-submit --deploy-mode client spark-job.py
```

and

```
$spark-submit spark-job.py
```

If you specify `--master yarn`, now it will run in yarn in client mode.

Note:
--master The master URL for the cluster (e.g. for standalone cluster spark://23.195.26.187:7077)
  Types of mode
  *standalone
  *YARN
  *Mesos
  *Kubernetes

--deploy-mode: Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (cluster) or locally as an external client (client) (default: client)
  *client
  *cluster